# Dynamically generating date range starts in SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, sql-server-2012, range

Imagine you have a set of dates. You want any date which is within X days of the lowest date to be "merged" into that date. Then you want to repeat until you have merged all date points.

For example:

| ID | DatePoints |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 |
| 3 | 2023-01-12 |
| 4 | 2023-01-21 |
| 5 | 2023-02-01 |
| 6 | 2023-02-02 |
| 7 | 2023-03-01 |

If you applied this rule to this data using 10 days as your X, you would end up with this output:

| DateRangeStarts |
| --- |
| 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-12 |
| 2023-02-01 |
| 2023-03-01 |

IDs 1 and 2 into range 1, IDs 3 and 4 into range 2, IDs 5 and 6 into range 3, and ID 7 into range 4.

Is there any way to do this without a loop? Answer can work in SQL Server or BigQuery. Thanks

Comment: SQL Server or BigQuery, either is fine

Comment: What happens if you have 2023-01-03? Does 2023-01-12 get merged into 2023-01-03 and then 2023-01-03 gets merged into 2023-01-01?

Comment: @EdmCoff No, it's based only off of the minimum. So the lowest date starts the range and consumes whatever is in X days.

Comment: I think you may need to do a GROUP BY calling a custom function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider something like the following. It's not pretty and I'm not at all confident it is the best solution, but I do think it works. Maybe it's a good starting point for you to work from.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT min(datepoint) datepoint
  FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT min(t.datepoint) OVER() datepoint
  FROM test t CROSS APPLY (SELECT max(cte.datepoint) OVER() md FROM cte) c
  WHERE t.datepoint > DATEADD(DAY, 10, c.md)
)
SELECT distinct datepoint
FROM cte
ORDER BY datepoint
```

(You might want to change the `>` to a `>=`, depending on what counts as within X days.)

The basic idea is to get the minimum date from your table into the cte, then recursively get the minimum date from your table that is bigger than the current maximum date in the cte + X days.

It gets messy because of the limitations SQL Server places on recursive CTEs. They can't be used in subqueries, with normal `OUTER JOIN`s, or with aggregate functions. Therefore, I use `CROSS APPLY` and the window versions of `min`/`max`. This gets the correct result, but multiple times, so I'm forced to use `DISTINCT` to clean it up afterward.

Depending on your data, it might be better to do a loop anyway, but I think this is an option to consider.

Here's a [Fiddle of it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/K5CKmJsx).

Comment: Appreciate it, yeah I think loop or recursion is the best and maybe only way to go on this one.